# Get more than 1 value from JDBC connection using Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, jdbc, google-apps-script

I have a JDBC connection to MSSQL using GAS, the database I am using has class names and dates that are associated with the specific class.

I'm trying to retrieve all of the dates associated with the class **Advanced Ventilator Skills Review**. When I run the below code all I see in the log is the last date added to the database that is associated with the class above. Can anyone help me out? I want to get all of the dates associated with the class and what would be optimal is to display those dates in a drop down menu.

```
//Read from Database
function read(e) {

   var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

var conn = Jdbc.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://IPAddress:1433;" +
   "databaseName=databaseName;user=User;password=Password;");

  var stmt = conn.createStatement();
  var rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * from dbo.tbl_ClassDetail WHERE className = 'Advanced Ventilator Skills Review'");


  while(rs.next()) {
    var class = rs.getString('className');
    var date = rs.getString('classDate');
    var time = rs.getString('classTime');
  }

  Logger.log(date);

  rs.close();
  stmt.close();
  conn.close();

}
```

Comment: Have you tried moving the line `Logger.log(date);` inside the `while` loop?

Comment: That appeared to work, thank you!

Comment: @LukeWoodward
Do you by chance know how to display those values within a listbox?

Comment: No, I haven't used GAS before, and that's why I didn't write a full answer.  All I could do was tell you why you were only seeing the last date in the log.

Answer (score 0):

1. collect the results into array *results.push(class,date,time)* in while loop. return results from this function
2. Using example from https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_listbox, and in your show or UiApp - take the results array returned and add them in a for or while loop

   var results = read(e);

   for (i=0; i < results.length; i++) 
        {
           lb.addItem [i][1];

   ```
   }
   ```